# jQuery not working in MVC and IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I have the below in _layout.html in MVC to show a modal dialog box on page:

```
<head>
    <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src='Scripts/modal/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/modal/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/modal/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="Scripts/modal/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/modal/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modla: true,
                show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });

            jQuery("#opener").click(function() {
                jQuery("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

But i keep getting the below error:
0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

The same error when i replace jQuery with '$'

Please help

Comment: Why have you added 3 versions of jQuery?

Comment: also look at the rendered html.  i am guessing that you have script above where the jquery is defined

Comment: Do the jQuery scripts files that you are referencing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the way you linked your jQuery files.

Don't give relative paths to JavaScript files in your layout page, the relative path will change depending on the page you are browsing. Add `~\` before the paths:

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src='~/Scripts/modal/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/modal/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="~/Scripts/modal/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You have also linked jQuery multiple times. If you really want to use different versions of jQuery do something like this:

```
!-- load jQuery 1.10.1 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/modal/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j1101 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.9.1 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/modal/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Here you can use jQuery 1.9.1 by calling `$` and jQuery 1.10.1 by calling `$j1101`

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft MVC, it better to use @Styles.Render method to load css and JS. You can also config the js/css files at App_Start\BundleConfig.cs
Another tip: you should also place attribute type="text/javascript"  in the script tag.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")

<script type="text/javascript">You javascript here</script>
```